# Error in processing special symbols XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Tz9.jpg)I process xml-documents using `XmlDocument` in C#:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument ();    
xml.Load(file);
```

I have faced the following problem:

In a number of documents there is a special symbol: `&#167` (it is a symbol `§`)

It isn't distinguished while processing and so the document doesn't open in Word.
(Word error when processing the XML file. Inadmissible sign XML)

It would be desirable that after processing symbols `&#167` remained on the places.

May be someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you give a (short) example file?

Comment: It's not clear where Word comes into this, to be honest... is the problem in your C# code, in Word, or somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you, guys!
Here is the short example of the part of my file before processing:
<w:t>{ОГЛ_В=2_&#167; 1. Общие положения}</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:vanish/><w:color w:val="800000"/></w:rPr>
<w:t>{М=100264}</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:color w:val="FF0000"/></w:rPr>
<w:t>&#167; 1</w:t></w:r><w:r>

Comment: I also have added printscreen of this part after processing it using C#

Comment: @andrew1989 Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information

Answer (score 0):

This is a detailed microsoft article on how to do this. Essentially you will need to load the xml file and replace the special characters using StreamWriter.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316063

Answer (score 0):

The `&#167` is not symbol `§`

The `&#167;` is symbol `§`

The xml file will ivalid if there is something like `&#167`. It have to be `&#167;`
One of possible solution is read the file just like a text then replace all `&#167` to `&#167;`, save and finally open it as xml

Comment: Thank you!
My xml have &#167; but after processing it the symbol &#167; isn't recognized and the file have become broken

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "after processing"?

Comment: I mean after loading and saving xml:
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument ();    
xml.Load(file);
***
xml.Save(file);

Between this operations I do nothing with &#167;

Comment: @andrew1989 where is an error, in `xml.Load(file)` or in `xml.Save(file)`?

Comment: error occures after saving. The document can't be opened by Word. 
I try to fix it replacing § --> &#167; but after saving file this symbol is &amp;#167; . But I need &#167;

Comment: Where is your code where you open document by Word? Could you show us more details. And please see [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't open document by Word in C#. It is made later by users who use Word to open xml-documents.
I use only xml.Load() to work with xml
P.S. It is my first question here:)